# How to access an element that is placed next to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following html structure:

```
<span class="thump">1</span>
<a class="tp" href="#" programm="5">Post</a>
```

Now I want to write thump according to programm attribute. This is how I get the the a element according to the programm number:

```
$("a.tp[programm='" + programm + "']");
```

How do I refer to the thump element that is next to this a element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var anchor = $("a.tp[programm='" + programm + "']");
var thump = anchor.prev();
```

Or if there is only one thump element (previous is recommended, especially if they are adjacent elements):

```
var anchor = $("a.tp[programm='" + programm + "']");
var thump = anchor.siblings('.thump');
```

Comment: The right approach, but your answer is a little confusing. Firstly, if they are adjacent, all that is required is .prev() without a selector, and then you say "or if there is one thump element" but then go on to show how you would select multiple siblings.